# debug assertion failed in debug mode

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, mfc, assertion

When I tried to run my app in debug mode, I got "Debug Assertion Failed! Program C:\Windows\system32\mfc110d.dll File: f:......\afxwin1.inl Lie: 21...." message.
This message occurs in the following and it happens in debug mode only.

```
if (!ProcessShellCommand(cmdInfo))
    return FALSE;
```

[image]
[image]

I'm using Visual studio 2017 and some DLLs(built in VS 2012).
Also, it is okay under Visual Studio 2012.
Could you tell me what is wrong?

Comment: Trace in to see what assert you are hitting. And if you don't need the command line, just get rid of it. I've used home brew and boost program_options instead of the MFC method as it is sort of dumb.

Comment: A little searching on a `AfxGetInstanceHandle( )` assertion reveals that mixing dlls from different builds is bad juju. If you have 2012 installed, you can change to that compiler. in General->Platform Toolset.

Comment: lakeweb Thanks for answer. Yes, it is okay under 2012 toolset. No more solution?

Comment: I use VS2015 now. But I have one big project that I still use the vs100 toolset on. Half a dozen dlls that go along with it. It will be a big job but I know I have to do all of it at once. If your objective is to move up, you have to take everything with it. Just the way it works.

Comment: When I use DLLs built in release mode, it works without assertion. Of course these DLLs are not my part.

Comment: @Won Young Lee, It still has some differences in two modes like this case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34434758/debug-assertion-failed-error-when-changing-from-release-mode-to-debug-mode, in addition, generally it would has certain compatibility issue if you update the old project to the higher VS version directly. If it works well using the VS2012 toolset, you would think about the dll files build in VS2012.

Comment: Show us the callstack, and the code line of the ASSERT.

Comment: You said "and some DLLs(built in VS 2012)". Search the assertion. This happens when you mix dlls from different builds. The only solution I know of is _don't mix dlls._ Either roll back the toolset on your project or get those other dlls built with the new compiler.

Comment: @xMRi I uploaded the callstack.

Comment: @lakeweb Correct it. "and some DLLs..." means "all DLLs are built in VS2012, however, app is built under 2017 toolset.

Comment: The problem is not the EXE. The problem is a DLL you use XImageViewD! You have no valid initialies CWinApp object in the DLL. What kind of DLL is it? Regular, Extension DLL? Do you share the MFC in a DLL?

Comment: Next time, don't copy pictures copy text!

Comment: Why won't you either build your dlls with 2017 or roll back your project toolset? It is a one click test to roll the project back and confirm the problem.

Comment: @Won Young Lee, Just update your dll files and the whole project to VS2017, and then re-refer to these dll files, how about the result now?